# SqlAlchemy - How to commit when saving huge amount of data?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Imagine 1 000 000 of records with 30 columns that should be saved by batches of size 100 000 records. What is the proper way for committing? I mean should I commit every time after saving every batch or after all batches (see code below)?

```
from more_itertools import sliced
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def batcher(sequence, batch_size):
    for batch in sliced(sequence, batch_size):
        yield batch

def save(session, batch: list[list]):
    # some random logic.  here IndexError can happen
    # saving batch logic
    # do session.commit() here??? <====== 1

data = [
    [1,2, ..., 30],
    [10, 20, ..., 300],
    # 1 000 000 row
]

session = Session()

try:
    for batch in batcher(data, batch_size=100_000):
        save(session, batch)
except:
    session.rollback()

# or do session.commit() here???  <====== 2
```

1. If commit after all (2) where data are stored before saving and how data are saved into database (all 1 000 000 records)?
2. If commit after every batch (1) rollback not working after IndexError. How to rollback properly? Should I flush instead of commit?

Comment: it doesn't really matter. commits and atomic transactions only matter if someone else might be trying to modify some of the data at the same time, but here it seems like you're just doing a bulk insert.